# ReactNative: Pass JS variable to AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

Exactly as in Title guys.

I've already passed variables as arguments to native modules through `RCT_EXPORT_MODULE`, and I'm aware of `RCT_CUSTOM_VIEW_PROPERTY`, although this is for 'callable' components, and I'm not sure it can be used to pass a JS variable to `AppDelegate.m`, neither how to do it.

Anyone was able to do this? Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this package `react-native-config` and it does the job greatly!

Here's their github: https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config

If someone come's up with a better answer, I'll mark it as the right answer ;)

Comment: brilliant! That's what I was looking for.